# How to uncheck all the checkboxs

Tags: visualforce

How to uncheck all the checkboxes, when a user click on CommandButton? I tried with the below code but it is not working.

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="unCheckAll(this)"  
 style="left:30px;position:relative;" 
 value="Clear" action="{!clear}" rerender="Selected_PBS"   />


function unCheckAll(cb)
{
    var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
    {
        if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
        inputElem[i].checked = false;
    }
}
```

here is my entire source code:

```
<apex:page controller="vfp_bom_Controller" showheader="true">

<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock id="accountList" title="Available Accounts" >

        <style type="text/css">
            .showContacts {
                background: transparent url('/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
            }
            .hideContacts {
                background: transparent url('/img/alohaSkin/twisty_sprite.png') 0 -11px no-repeat;
            }
        </style>
<div id="InnternalDiv" style="overflow:auto;height:350px;" >
        <!-- first grid -->
       <apex:pageblocktable id="accountList" value="{!AllAccounts}" var="acc">
            <apex:column headervalue="Set as Primary">                    
               <apex:actionsupport action="{!LoadAccountContactByAccountId}" event="onclick" rerender="selectedContactList">  
                <input type="radio" name="Account" />                    
                    <apex:param name="accountId" value="{!acc.Id}">
                </apex:param></apex:actionsupport>                            
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headervalue="AccountNumber">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.AccountNumber}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column> 
            <apex:column headervalue="Name">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Name}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column>  
            <apex:column headervalue="NumberOfEmployees">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.NumberOfEmployees}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column>  
            <apex:column headervalue="Site">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!acc.Site}">
            </apex:outputfield></apex:column>  
        </apex:pageblocktable>
</div>


    <!-- second grid -->
    <apex:pageblock id="selectedContactList"  title="{!IF(accountList != NULL && accountList.size > 0,'Selected Contact','There are no records selected')}">
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="{!accountList.size!=0}"> 
            <table id="tableAccount" class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="headerRow">
                        <th class="actionColumn">Action</th>
                        <th>Account Name</th>
                        <th>Industry</th>
                        <th>Billing Country</th>
                        <th>Createdby</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <apex:repeat id="repeatAccount" value="{!accountList}" var="item">
                        <apex:variable var="acc" value="{!item.oAccount}" />   
                            <tr id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:account" class="dataRow">
                                <td class="actionColumn">
                                        <!--<apex:inputCheckbox id="selectAccountRow" value="{!item.IsSelected}"         
                                                            onclick="javascript:toggleSelectAll(this, '{!$Component.repeatAccount}');"/> -->

                                        <apex:inputCheckbox >
                                            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!Selected}" onsubmit="checkAll(this)" rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
                                        </apex:inputCheckbox>  
                                </td>
                                <td class="dataCell">
                                    <apex:outputLink id="linkShowHide" value="javascript:toggleContactRow('{!$Component.repeatAccount}')">
                                            <img id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:Img" src="/s.gif" class="showContacts" 
                                                    border="0" height="11px" width="11px" style="padding-right: 4px;"/>
                                        <apex:outputField value="{!acc.Name}" />
                                    </apex:outputLink>
                                </td>
                                    <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.Industry}" /></td>
                                    <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.billingcountry}" /></td>
                                    <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!acc.CreatedById}" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr id="{!$Component.repeatAccount}:Contact" class="dataRow" style="display:none;">
                                    <td colspan="100" style="padding:10px; padding-left: 45px;">
                                        <apex:pageBlock >
                                            <h2>Contacts Detail by Account</h2>


                                        <apex:outputPanel layout="none">                                            
                                            <table id="tableAccountContacts" class="list" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr class="headerRow">
                                                        <th class="actionColumn">Action</th> 
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Email</th>
                                                        <th>Phone</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <apex:repeat id="repeatAccountContacts" value="{!item.contactSet}" var="subitem">
                                                        <apex:variable value="{!subitem.oContact}" var="con" />
                                                        <tr class="dataRow">
                                                           <!--<td class="actionColumn">
                                                                <apex:inputCheckbox id="selectContactRow" styleclass="ContactCheckbox" value="{!subitem.IsSelected}"/>
                                                            </td>  -->

                                                            <td class="actionColumn">                                                               
                                                                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!subitem.isSelected}" id="checkedone"> 
                                                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!Selected}" rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
                                                                </apex:inputCheckbox>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="dataCell"><apex:outputField value="{!con.Name}" /></td>
                                                            <td class="dataCell"><apex:inputText id="email" value="{!con.email}"/></td>
                                                            <td class="dataCell"><apex:inputText id="phone" value="{!con.phone}"/></td>
                                                        </tr> 
                                                    </apex:repeat>                                                     
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </apex:outputPanel></apex:pageBlock>  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </apex:repeat>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </apex:outputPanel> </apex:pageblock>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        function toggleContactRow(rowId) {
            try {
                var AccountImg = jQuery(document.getElementById(rowId + ":Img"));
                var ContactsRow = jQuery(document.getElementById(rowId + ":Contact"));
                if (AccountImg.hasClass("hideContacts")) {
                    AccountImg.attr("class", "showContacts");
                    ContactsRow.hide();
                }
                else {
                    AccountImg.attr("class", "hideContacts");
                    ContactsRow.show();
                }
            }
            catch (e) { alert(e); }
        }  

        function toggleSelectAll(elCheckbox, rowId) {
            try {
                var SelectAll = jQuery(elCheckbox);
                var ContactsRow = jQuery(document.getElementById(rowId + ":Contact"));
                ContactsRow.find(".ContactCheckbox").each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).prop("checked", SelectAll.is(":checked"));
                });
            }
            catch (e) { alert(e); }
        }

        function checkAll(cb)
        {
            var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
            {
                if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-1)
                inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
            }
        }    
    </script>  


</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>  
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should unselect all radio's via jQuery, if you need regular javascript simply adapt as necessary. Modify selector as needed

```
j$('input.radio').each(function() {            
            j$(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
```

for checkboxes:

```
j$('input.checkbox').each(function() {            
            j$(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
```

Comment: how would you call that JS by doing this? `<apex:commandButton onclick="unCheckAll(this)"  value="Clear" action="{!clear}" rerender="Selected_PBS"   />` ?

Comment: I would not use (this) as that would be the command button. You could either wrap my answer in a function and call it, or you could pass a selector and use that instead of what is currently there.

Answer (score 0):

take help from the below example:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!selectAll }" label="Select All" styleclass="parentcheck" />
```

// part of your code below:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!subitem.isSelected}" id="checkedone" styleclass="childcheck"> 
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!Selected}" rerender="Selected_PBS"/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

// in script---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".parentCheck").click(function() {
            $(".childCheck").prop('checked', this.checked);

        });
        $(".childCheck").click(function(){
            if ($('input.childCheck[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length){
                $("#parentCheck").removeAttr('checked');    
            }else{
                $("#parentCheck").prop('checked',true);
            }
        });
    })
```

When you will select the selectAll checkbox, it will automatically select all the other checkboxes.

Comment: where is the parentCheck? selector coming from?

Comment: use parentcheck in the main checkbox.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand but my checkbox name is `checkedone` i do not have childCheck, have you looked at my source code?

Comment: create a seperate checkbox . when you will select the parent checkbox(newly created) all the other checkboxes( in your repeat) will be checked and vice versa.. give styleclass 'parentcheck' in the new parent checkbox. and styleclass 'childcheck' in your checkbox 'checkedone'

Comment: I'm not following you unless you edit your answer with more explanation or you can modify the source code i have posted, sorry but hard to understand what exactly you trying to do.

Comment: no problem.. i hv updated my answer